# Adjust the font of scrlttr2 to the serif font of moderncv

Tags: fonts, koma-script, moderncv, latin-modern, scrlttr2

I'm a newbie in LaTeX & trying to make my cv with it.

I'm almost finished, the last thing is ...

I made my cv with `moderncv`, the letter with `scrlttr 2` and the cover with `scrartcl`. this 3 have different font.

How can I adjust the font of `scrlttr2` & `scrartcl` to `moderncv`.

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% character encoding
% -------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
%
\pagestyle{empty}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% adjust the page margins
% -------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[scale=1]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Positionierung der Textelemente
% -------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% personal data
% -------------------------------------------------
\def\firstname{Max}
\def\familyname{Mustermann}
\def\FileAuthor{\firstname \familyname}
\def\FileSubject{Deckblatt}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Font
% -------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Aus der moderncvstylecasual.sty:
% -------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{blau}{rgb}{0.20,0.40,0.65}
\definecolor{hellblau}{rgb}{0.25,0.50,0.75}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.95,0.55,0.15}
\definecolor{gruen}{rgb}{0.30,0.65,0.15}
\definecolor{rot}{rgb}{0.95,0.20,0.20}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}
\definecolor{schwarz}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\newcommand*{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{25}{27}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}
\newcommand*{\familynamefont}{\firstnamefont}
\newcommand*{\titel}{\fontsize{25}{27}\mdseries\upshape}
\newcommand*{\inhalt}{\fontsize{15}{17}\mdseries\upshape}
%
\begin{document}
\sffamily
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Titel
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{10}(1,2)
\color{dunkelgrau}{
 \bfseries \begin{Large}\titel{BEWERBUNGSUNTERLAGEN}\end{Large}}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
% -------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}

\begin{textblock}{10}(12.9,16.999)
\color{blau}{\inhalt{
    \begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{-1pt}
        \item Anschreiben
        \vspace{0.1cm}
        \item Lebenslauf
        \vspace{0.1cm}      
        \item Notenbogen bzw. Vordiplom
        \vspace{0.1cm}      
        \item Empfehlungsschreiben
        \vspace{0.1cm}      
        \item Abiturzeugnis
    \end{itemize}
}}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Vertikaler Strich oben
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{1}(13.5,0)
    \color{hellblau}{\vrule width 2pt height 17cm}
\end{textblock}


% -------------------------------------------------
% Vertikaler Striche Mitte
% -------------------------------------------------

%\begin{textblock}{1}(13.5,17.3)
%\color{hellblau}{\vrule width 2pt height 0.5cm}
%\end{textblock}
%
%\begin{textblock}{1}(13.5,18.16)
%\color{hellblau}{\vrule width 2pt height 0.5cm}
%\end{textblock}


% -------------------------------------------------
% Vertikaler Strich Unten
% -------------------------------------------------

\begin{textblock}{1}(13.5,12)
\color{hellblau}{\vrule width 2pt height 0.5cm}
\end{textblock}


%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Passfoto
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{3}(10.9,21.9)
    %\fbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{foto}}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Anschrift
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{9.7}(1,8)
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace{-3.5cm}
        {\bfseries \begin{large}\firstnamefont{\color{hellgrau}{\firstname}}~\familynamefont{\color{dunkelgrau}{\familyname}}\end{large}}\\[.35ex]
        \huge\itshape%
        straße\\
        plz ort\\[.35ex]
        \Telefon~+tel\\
        \Letter~{mail}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Hintergrundbild
% -------------------------------------------------
% \begin{textblock}{13.5}(0,0)
%   \includegraphics[width=13.5cm, height=\textheight]{firma}
% \end{textblock}
%

\end{document}
```

LETTER

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{color}


% Aus der moderncvstylecasual.sty:
%BLAU:
\definecolor{blau}{rgb}{0.20,0.40,0.65}
%ORANGE:
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.95,0.55,0.15}
%GRÜN:
\definecolor{gruen}{rgb}{0.30,0.65,0.15}
%ROT:
\definecolor{rot}{rgb}{0.95,0.20,0.20}
%GRAU:
\definecolor{grau}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}



\KOMAoptions{
fromalign=right, 
fromrule=aftername, 
addrfield=true, 
backaddress=on, 
pagenumber=botright, 
foldmarks=false, 
fromphone=true, 
fromemail=true 
}


\LoadLetterOption{KOMAold}


\setkomavar{fromname}{Vorname Nachname} \setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hauptstr. 12\\ 12345 Ort} \setkomavar{fromemail}{name@mail.de} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{555 9873} 
\setkomavar{signature}{Vorname Nachname} 


\begin{document} 

\begin{letter}{Mega-Firma\\
               Schlossallee 12\\
               23456 Hauptstadt} 


%Der Betreff soll blau + fett gedruckt werden:
\opening{\bfseries{\textcolor{blau}{Ihre Stellenanzeige in der FAZ}}} 


Lieber Personalmensch, \\

blabla

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen} 

\vspace*{2cm}
\encl{ 
Lebenslauf\\
Zeugnisse}

\end{letter} 
\end{document}

}
```

CV

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]{casual, classic}



%Wenn cventry genutzt wird entfernt es die Punkte
%
%\renewcommand*{\cvline}[7][.25em]{%
%  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
%    {\bfseries#3}%
%%   \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}% I changed this line (with comma) ...
%    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{ {\slshape#4}}% ... into this one (without comma).
%    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
%    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
%    .\strut%
%    \ifx&#7&%
%      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%änderung der Spaltenbreite des Datum
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}    
\firstname{Bob}
\familyname{Marley}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{bla}{bla}
\mobile{0176/ 10044015}
%\phone{09876/ 5 43 21}

%\photo[4cm]{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle



%\cvline{}{}{}{}{}{}
\section{Studium}
\cvline{4/2013--aktuell}{\textbf{Allgemeiner Maschinenbau M.Sc.} \newline RWTH-Aachen University, \emph{Note: 1,9}.}






Berlin, \today
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they’re either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [_minimal_ working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: In particular, think about which aspects of the current style you want to change. Right now it is impossible to guess.

Answer (score 5):

Remove `\sffamily` from the `scrartcl` (if you want to, also from the definition of `\firstnamefont`), and `\usepackage{cmbright}` and `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}` from `scrlttr2`. Then, all three documents will be using the Latin Modern Serif fonts, like your `moderncv` (loaded through the package `lmodern`).

When you’re running into a problem next time, *please* take the time to construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (and do take a minute to look into that question I’m linking to) – you’ll find the solution yourself if you just comment out lines from your document and see what changes. Basically, that’s what I did to find the solution. It’s good that you posted a full, compilable document (or rather three), but they all are quite far from minimal.

Looking at your problem from the perspective of a MWE, the answer would be: Either do nothing (`moderncv` uses Latin Modern Serif, the KOMA-Script classes use Computer Modern Serif, which look the same to the untrained eye), or load `lmodern`, and `fontenc` with the `T1` in `scrartcl` and `scrlttr2`:

### `moderncv` minimal

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\end{document}
```

### `scrartcl` minimal

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

### `scrlttr2` minimal

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
Wanderlust
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user42664 Glad it helped! Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem. I hope the minimal documents also gave you some insight into the approach of minimalizing a document, which should usually be done before you post a question here. (It doesn’t need to be _that_ short, but there was a lot left to cut away from your code.)